# Why the horizontal scroll bars?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

I was just looking around on my gaming.stackexchange.com profile and noticed some unnecessary horizontal scroll bars.

[image]

Comment: Repro on Chrome 9. There is a `width: 100%` on the `<table class="summary-title">` which will remove the scroll bars when disabled.

Comment: I get it on Firefox v3.5.15 and IE 8

Comment: I guess it's all over the network (not just *gaming*) and happens when there is no paging. Agree it's really annoying.

Comment: Repro on Safari 5.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed a while ago - an artifact of floats and overflow.  It's also something we have a long-term fix in mind for as well, but that will take many, *many* many days and design time to complete.